# What monitor is a good choice for graphic design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, illustration, color-reproduction, monitor

Hi guys illustrators and designers.
I curious what monitor is good for graphic design (Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign...)?
What screen resolution you recommend? What brand and how many inches the diagonal?

Comment: Hardware questions are generally off topic here on GDSE. If you are looking for recommendations probably best to have a look at online reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot write here something like "Buy Delsungcer 1234 A7, it's the best!!!!!" because only an idiot would believe it and we generally have no intention to push brands.

You have two reasonable possiblities. Buy the best you can afford or the cheapest which does the least acceptable minimum of the job.

The size: How old you are? Only 20? then you can probably work with 15 in diameter monitor. If you are forty, that would be difficult due the degradation of the sight. You must see easily program icons and the covered area must be in pixels so large that photos can be seen as whole. If you have the needed room a good idea is to have 2 monitors. One for program controls and the other for the image under work.

The prices of the monitors are so low that a good 27 in monitor is surely affordable for most of us and 24 in monitors is even more. No reason to accept anything smaller except the available space.

4k video works need that capable monitor and big enough in inches to make realistic judgement possible. But for usual image editing works with 27 in monitor with 1920 X 1200 pixels should be enough; only young people can see its pixels without a looking glass. Generally also 2560 x 1440 pixels is available for reasonable prices. Get it if you still have sharp sight and do not need 4k.

Graphic works need reliable colors. A display with stunning movie or game colors can be useless. You should check color measurements. Does the display cover full sRGB color range? That can be considered as a minimum. Full Adobe RGB range would be better altough not needed for web works. Beware sub-sRGB range displays. They can be good for office works, but I cannot recommend them for color image creation nor editing.

How accurately it shows colors and brightness? That depend on the used technology. Serious graphic workers often have hardware color calibrator.

Viewing angle without too much color or contrast degradation must be large enough. The used display technology  affects much. Some displays are useless if one cannot keep his eyes always in the same place plus minus 10 cm.

You can easily find websites which check displays. They check the practical usability as well as image performance including how reliably it shows the colors without calibration and calibrated. One example:

https://tftcentral.co.uk

They have a display purchase selector, where you input a few things:

[image]

The result shows those models that they can recommend. The recommendations are based on their mile long test articles and measurements.

**Do not believe ads.** Marketing people work very hard to push non-relevant technical properties to seem important. One example: Contrast ratio. Every monitor can have infinite contrast ratio. Only pull at first the power cord off. Then compare the unpowered brightness (after waiting the latent fluorescence has been decayed) to the absolute maximum. Some displays switch the light off behind large black areas only to make this number big without lying. You should watch black depth, available luminance and luminance uniformity instead.

Another popular marketing trick is to try to make a trade mark to look out a technical property and insert to it a meaningless, but good looking numerical value. (like "Clean-O'Wiew sharpness optimization with 200% enhancement").

Comment: thank you user287001 very much for your time and so wide answer, really appreciate this.
Now, when I returned back NEC EA271U 4k monitor to a seller, I doubt between two new options:
1) https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1435874-REG/nec_ea271q_bk_sv_27_wqhd_desktop_monitor.html with 2560x1440
2) https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1368968-REG/nec_multisync_pa243w_bk_sv_24_wide.html 1920x1200 with a more wide gamut: Adobe RGB Coverage/Size: 112.4% / 99.6%
NTSC Coverage/Size: 107.4% / 97.1%
sRGB and Rec. 709 Coverage / Size: 151.6% / 100.0%

Comment: @VictorChernobay just curious: One covers 112,4% of Adobe RGB, but only 97,1% of sRGB, which is fully included in Adobe RGB. Maybe an error somewhere.

Comment: Finally I've gave back 27" NEC EA271U  with 4k, weak and poor construction materials and not so wide gamut. Instead I took NEC PA243W which has true blue color comparing with previous one, professional color gamut. So, my conclusion is that for working with color graphics, photo editing, printing material the PA IPS film is right choice comparing with just IPS

Comment: A premium choice -, but surely worth the money, if you need that color accuracy.